# Write a function named find_mismatch that accepts two strings as input arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to write this function but I am stuck. Just trying to do some practice on spring break. If any one has a whole new approach I am open. I know this code is a sad sight, but I cannot wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance.

- 0 if the two strings match exactly.
- 1 if the two strings have the same length and mismatch in only one character.
- 2 if the two strings do not have the same length or mismatch in two or more characters.

code:

```
void findMismatch (const string s1, const string s2)

    {int count;
if (s1.length() != s2.length())

     {
        cout <<"2"<< endl;
     }
if (s1 == s2)

    {
        cout <<"0"<< endl;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is findMismatch() supposed to do?

Comment: Yea sorry just edited.

Comment: You are asked to write a function named "find_mismatch" and you name it "findMismatch"?

Comment: I suppose you need to write a loop that counts how many characters match and how many do not (and consider working on indenting code properly -easier for others to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I put together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void findMismatch(string s1, string s2)
{   

    if(s1.length() != s2.length())
    {
        cout<<"2"<<endl;
    }
    else if(s1 == s2) //exact match
    {
        cout<<"0"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {

        int mismatchCount = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < s1.length() && mismatchCount<=1)
        {
            if(s1.at(i) != s2.at(i) && ++mismatchCount == 2)
            {
                cout<<"2"<<endl;
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"1"<<endl;
    }


}
int main()
{
  findMismatch("Achr","Acha"); //one mismatch
  findMismatch("Achrfs","Achaee"); //two or more mismatch
  findMismatch("Ach","Ach"); //exact match
  findMismatch("Achrfdfd","Acha"); //different lengths
}
```